# jaspersoft studio - bar chart category issue

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart

I have designed below bar chart in jaspersoft studio, but its not the one what i want. My expected result is given below. Even this may be the basic question, since i am totally new to this report/chart generation work. So it would be much appreciated if someone guide me to get the desired result.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2017-04-11T10:51:06 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="dummychart" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="6af21e76-9897-424c-935c-909188c48f39">
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="QC DB"/>
 <queryString>
  <![CDATA[select t1.supplier,sum(t2.qty) as received,sum(t2.accepted_qty) as accepted,sum(t2.rejected_qty) as rejected
from qc_master t1
join qc_item_list t2 on t2.i_rep_no = t1.i_rep_no
and t1.cdate between '01-03-2017' and '01-04-2017'
and t2.accepted_qty <> 'null'
and t2.insp_date <> 'null'
group by t1.supplier]]>
 </queryString>
 <field name="SUPPLIER" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <field name="RECEIVED" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
 <field name="ACCEPTED" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
 <field name="REJECTED" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
 <background>
  <band splitType="Stretch"/>
 </background>
 <title>
  <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
 </title>
 <summary>
  <band height="399" splitType="Stretch">
   <barChart>
    <chart evaluationTime="Report">
     <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="798" height="399" uuid="4121a817-1fdb-4c0c-81be-2bf388061d09"/>
     <chartTitle/>
     <chartSubtitle/>
     <chartLegend/>
    </chart>
    <categoryDataset>
     <categorySeries>
      <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{RECEIVED}]]></seriesExpression>
      <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{SUPPLIER}]]></categoryExpression>
      <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{RECEIVED}]]></valueExpression>
      <labelExpression><![CDATA[]]></labelExpression>
     </categorySeries>
     <categorySeries>
      <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{ACCEPTED}]]></seriesExpression>
      <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{SUPPLIER}]]></categoryExpression>
      <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{ACCEPTED}]]></valueExpression>
     </categorySeries>
     <categorySeries>
      <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{REJECTED}]]></seriesExpression>
      <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{SUPPLIER}]]></categoryExpression>
      <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{REJECTED}]]></valueExpression>
     </categorySeries>
    </categoryDataset>
    <barPlot>
     <plot/>
     <itemLabel/>
     <categoryAxisFormat>
      <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
     </categoryAxisFormat>
     <valueAxisFormat>
      <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
     </valueAxisFormat>
    </barPlot>
   </barChart>
  </band>
 </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

[image]

expected one
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        <categoryDataset>
            <categorySeries>
                <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Received"]]></seriesExpression>
                <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{SUPPLIER}]]></categoryExpression>
                <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{RECEIVED}]]></valueExpression>
            </categorySeries>
            <categorySeries>
                <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Accepted"]]></seriesExpression>
                <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{SUPPLIER}]]></categoryExpression>
                <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{ACCEPTED}]]></valueExpression>
            </categorySeries>
            <categorySeries>
                <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Rejected"]]></seriesExpression>
                <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{SUPPLIER}]]></categoryExpression>
                <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{REJECTED}]]></valueExpression>
            </categorySeries>
        </categoryDataset>
```